# How do I avoid the first(and last) column of a x-capped chart being truncated?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, charts, mschart

I've been fiddling with a chart... I set the X axis minimum value to zero. Then I used `DataBindXY` on the `Chart.Series.First.Points` to set the values passing two lists (first is a 0-based label list and other has the actual values).

Below is the result. As I highlighted by the red arrow the first column is truncated.

[image: My chart]

Microsoft made traversing the settings of a chart in the designer as simple as getting out of a maze, so I'm clueless about where to find some offset property to be set.

---

*Edit:*
Mine could be a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454233/asp-net-chart-control-truncated-values-on-x-axis), but its answer is not clear to me, so I asked a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the X axis minimum value to -0.5, that should solve it.

```
GraphChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -0.5;
```

or try something like:

```
GraphChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0.5;
```

The reason is that the columns width is approximately 0.8 depending on the chart configuration so in your case they might span from 0.4 to 1.4, with a center point in 1